# Showing $\frac{1}{x^x}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\left[0,1\right] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by \begin{equation*}f(x) = \frac{1}{x^x}=\exp(-x\log x)\end{equation*} Then, as $-x$, $\log x$, and $\exp x$ are continuous on $\left(0,1\right]$, it is clear that $f$ is continuous on $\left(0,1\right]$. But how to show that $f$ is continuous at $0$?

Comment: For a start: You will have to fill a hole at $x=0$ and then you can make the function right-continuous, and then....

Comment: You need to give a definition to $f(0)$. You can show that if you define $f(0)=1$, then $f$ is continuous at $0$ (to do this, show that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{+}}x\log x =0$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3568204/continuity-of-x-lnx to see how to do this)).

Comment: Yes, I am using the convention that $0^0 = 1$. Thanks for the link.